# Best android library for recording a route in an android app

Tags: java, android

I am just learning how to write apps for android devices. I want to record the route of a user and save the location details as a file that I can later display using google maps api. I was hoping that there was a java library that I could use as a black box. I have tried googling but either nothing exists or probably I am using the wrong terminology. I come from a Perl background where it is easy to find a module using CPAN. I am sure there is an android or java equivalent, but for some reason I cannot find it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should I rephrase the question? I want to find out where all the open-source java libraries are available. The android equivalent of CPAN. I'm not sure how much room there is for opinions in the answer to that.

Comment: "where all the open-source java libraries are available" > that place is called the internet :) There is of course no centralized repository of *all* java open-source libraries, because there is too much of those and they can be developped by anyone who can choose to host it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a (soon-to-be-no-longer) open source Android app, My Tracks, that tracks your route (walking, driving, etc.). Check out the code for that, I believe you can export route data to CSV or some other serializable format.

Comment: Yes I use that app myself. Thanks for the suggestion. I imagine that is probably quite a large application and I may have trouble isolating the particular code that I need.